# How to make this code faster for finding the number of natural divisors for large numbers?

Tags: python

```
a = int(input())
f = 0
for i in range(1, a + 1):
    if a % i == 0:
        f += 1
print(f)
```

This code finds the number of natural divisors of the number a,how to make it faster for large numbers?

Comment: have either of the supplied answers helped you? Please mark one as correct if so, that way your question can be removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adapt a prime factor algorithm to count divisors by accumulating the combinations of primes that form the number.  This will still take (√N)/2 iterations if N is a prime number but it will reduce the number of iterations considerably when N has many prime factors.

```
def divCount(N):
    result = 1
    p,inc  = 2,1
    while p*p<=N:
        d = 1
        while N%p == 0:
            d  += 1
            N //= p
        result *= d
        p,inc   = p+inc,2
    if N>1: result *= 2
    return result
```

output (all less than 2 milliseconds):

```
divCount(12) --> 6

divCount(479001600) --> 792

divCount(479001599) --> 2    # prime number (10,944 iterations)
```

Comment: OP, this is a much better approach for extremely large numbers. My approach takes around 2-3 seconds for the numbers Alain tested on.

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with using `numpy`,

```py
r = np.arange(1, a + 1)
num_divisors = np.sum(a % r == 0)
```

This'll be much faster than a `for` loop. Unfortunately there's no way (as far as I'm aware) to count the number of divisors of an arbitrary integer without enumerating them via trial division.

Let `a = 12` and I'll break down each piece:

```py
>>> a = 12
>>> r = np.arange(1, a + 1)
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])
```

So `r` is just the integers from `1` to `a` inclusive, as a numpy array. Then performing modulus and the boolean equality comparison:

```py
>>> a % r == 0
array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True])
```

This is telling us all the values where the expression `12 % r == 0` evaluates to `True`, for all the values in `r`. Since `bool` is a subtype of `int`, we can take the sum of the boolean array directly, in order to find the number of divisors:

```py
>>> np.sum(a % r == 0)
6
```